# Linkedin api v2 - Problems when post

Tags: linkedin-api

I use linkedin v2 api and i`m having two problems:

1 - We have customer reports that when posting with us, the reach of the post is reduced dramatically.

2 - In addition, we find that when you publish an image via the API, Linkedin is adding a gray border. Even for images that follow the pattern indicated by your documentation.

Can you help with this issues?

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately, LinkedIn is still sending people here from there support. I will not be able to answer question 1. But for question 2 you should check out the following:

[Click here for more information about the images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/rich-media-shares#optimize-rich-media-shares-for-mobile)

> We recommend that you upload rich media in 1200 x 627 aspect ratio. Images uploaded in the recommended 1200 x 627 ratio are automatically displayed on the mobile app with white padding on the top/bottom or sides of the image, to fit the ratio without being cropped. Although a 3:2 aspect ratio, or 1200 x 800, displays fully without padding, we recommend using the industry-standard 1200 x 627 ratio. Link share thumbnail image uploads are displayed in a 2:1 ratio. Limit text in rich media images to the center of the image in a title-safe area.

Please go through this link https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/topics/6227/6237/81310/customizing-an-image-and-title-when-posting-a-url-on-your-linkedin-page?lang=en